# Grouping PHP Array on repeated events date value with array_flip modification

Tags: php, arrays

I am finding difficulty to group events on basis of repeated date values I am getting in my array. 
I have applied array_flip function to my array named as $element but it is not able to fulfill the requirements .

My input $element array is :

```
 $element = array(    
    "2/ 5/2"  => "",
    "2/ 6/22" => "",
    "2/ 7/22" => "AAHPM",
    "2/ 8/22" => "AAHPM",
    "2/ 9/22" => "AAHPM",
    "2/10/22" => "AAHPM",
    "2/11/22" => "AAHPM",
    "2/12/22" => "AAHPM",
    "2/13/22" => "",
    "2/14/22" => "School Administrator",
    "2/15/22" => "School Administrator",
    "2/16/22" => "School Administrator",
    "2/17/22" => "School Administrator",
    "2/18/22" => "School Administrator",
    "2/19/22" => "School Administrator",
    "2/20/22" => "",
    "2/21/22" => "",
    "2/22/22" => "AAHPM",
    "2/23/22" => "AAHPM",
    "2/24/22" => "AAHPM",
    "2/25/22" => "AAHPM",
    "2/26/22" => "AAHPM",
    "2/27/22" => "AAHPM",
    "2/28/22" => "AAHPM",
);
```

I applied this function :

```
$reverse  = array_flip($element);
```

The output I am getting now is :

```
Array
  (
      [ AAHPM ] => [ 2/28/22],
      [ School Administrator ] => [ 2/19/22 ],    
  )
```

My desired output is as AAHPN is repeating two times in elements array so I need them separately in an array :

```
 Array
  (
      [ AAHPM ] => [ 2/12/22, 2/28/22],
      [ School Administrator ] => [ 2/19/22 ],    
  )
```

I tried to acheive by doing the following instead of array_flip on $elements:

```
 $result = array();
    foreach($element as $k => $v) {
        if (array_key_exists($v, $result)) {
            $result[$v][] = $k;
        } else {
            $result[$v] = array($k);        
        }
    }
```

But the output I got is following :

```
Array
(
     [AAHPM] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  2/ 7/22
            [1] =>  2/ 8/22
            [2] =>  2/ 9/22
            [3] =>  2/10/22
            [4] =>  2/11/22
            [5] =>  2/12/22
            [6] =>  2/22/22
            [7] =>  2/23/22
            [8] =>  2/24/22
            [9] =>  2/25/22
           [10] =>  2/26/22
           [11] =>  2/27/22
           [12] =>  2/28/22
        )

        [School Administrator] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  2/14/22
            [1] =>  2/15/22
            [2] =>  2/16/22
            [3] =>  2/17/22
            [4] =>  2/18/22
            [5] =>  2/19/22
      )
)
```

Still I am not able to get the desired output.

Comment: _“Still I am not able to get the desired output.”_ - this should first of all come with a _proper_ explanation, by what logic you expect to arrive at that output in the first place! Use your _words_ to describe that, instead of just going, “I have, I want, you figure out the rest.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a temp variable and storing the last key value in it. On each iteration you can check the key value with temp variable. If it doesn't match then create a new array otherwise push in last array.

Here is how you can do it.

```
$result = array();
$temp = "";
foreach($element as $k => $v) {
    $modified_val = trim($v) == "" ? "null" : preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $v);
    if($temp == "" || $modified_val != $temp){
        $result[$modified_val][] = array($k);        
    }
    elseif($modified_val == $temp){
        if (array_key_exists($modified_val, $result)) {
            $lastindex = count($result[$modified_val]) - 1;
            $result[$modified_val][$lastindex][] = $k;
        } else {
            $result[$modified_val][] = array($k);        
        }
    }
    $temp = $modified_val == "" ? "null" : $modified_val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have written a function

```
<?php
function reverse($array){
   $output = array();
   foreach($array as $key => $value){
      if(!empty($value)){ //ignoring empty events
         $added = false;
         foreach($output as $k => $val){ //checking whether event added or not
            if($value == $k){
               $output[$k][] = $key;
               $added = true;
               break; //no need to checking further
            }
         }
         if(!$added){
            $output[$value] = array($key); 
         } //creating new event
      }
   }

   return $output;
}

$output = reverse($element);
?>
```

Comment: Its returning blank array.

Comment: just Updated ! :)

Comment: Not working its just showing this output :Array
(
    [AAHPM] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  2/12/22
        )

    [School Administrator] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  2/15/30
        )

)